# Installed fglrx from Software Center--screen goes black after login (monitor loses signal.)

Tags: graphic-drivers, proprietary

I have elementary OS freya installed and updated--works great.  Decided to try to `fglrx` from Software Center--kinda more glitchy than the open video drivers, but I wanted more FPS when playing online games--and for this it seems to do the trick.

That said, whenever my screen turns off or my computer is in suspend, when I wake it up, I have the normal login screen.  After typing my password, as soon as I hit 'enter' the screen goes black.  I can hear the 'pop' notification sound of my wireless connecting, but there is no mouse or anything.  After about 2 seconds my monitor says, "no signal" and the orange light comes on (just like it's asleep.)

I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and terminal pops up right away, then I can press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and my desktop pops up right away and everything is working fine again.

For the time beings, I have been logging in, opening terminal, then alt+f7 to get get back to desktop.  It works, but is there a way to fix this issue, or does anyone know what is happening?  This bug is slightly annoying.

I also noticed that AMD has `fglrx` version 15.7 while the Software Center has 15.2.  If I wanted to upgrade to 15.7 from the website, do I need to delete 15.2 first? Or will this be taken care of automatically when installing 15.7?

Comment: An additional thing I noticed.  If I turn off password needed upon sleep and suspend.  Once the screen is turned off, or the computer is suspended, upon hitting 'enter' I get right into my desktop correctly.  So, there seems to be some issue that occurs only while going from the login screen to the desktop.

Comment: to be sure i would delete fglrx 15.2 first before installing 15.7

Comment: Would using the Software Center and clicking 'delete' be good enough to delete fglrx 15.2 or would using command line: sudo apt-get purge fglrx be better?

Comment: Also, the release notes for fglrx 15.7 say I need to have glibc 2.2 or 2.3.  I believe my system has 2.1.  Do I need to update glibc?

Comment: i think the purge command is better. then you know it is completely gone of your system.  i mean everything of fglrx. 
here http://askubuntu.com/questions/646436/catalyst-15-7-could-it-run-on-ubuntu-15-04 you can find a way to install 15.7. 
Be warned i didn't test it. It is possible that you have to wait for the new hardware stack for ubuntu14.04. which will land in Freya around end august / september.

Comment: Thanks for the help Kay!  I'll read the link, I think I'll just wait it out and upgrade to 15.7 later since, besides the login black screen issue, my system is working great.